# OnSorting event not firing in GridView

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, datatable

I am reading data from XML and showing it in grid view. Problem is sorting is not working. It doesn't even fire **grid3_Sorting** method when I click on some column to do sort (I tested it by putting a break point)

This is my grid view and button control.

```
<asp:Button ID="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Click" />

<asp:GridView ID="grid3" runat="server" OnSorting="grid3_Sorting" AllowSorting="true"></asp:GridView>
```

This is code behind.

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlReader xmlFile;
    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("myxmlfile.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

    grid3.DataSource = ds.Tables["MyTABLE"];
    grid3.DataBind();
}

protected void grid3_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = grid3.DataSource as DataTable;
    if (dataTable != null)
    {
         DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
         dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression;

         grid3.DataSource = dataView;
         grid3.DataBind();
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing ID of submit button from "submit" to "sub"